# Characterizing sets of nullsets and specialness of complete sigma-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

When [completing a measure space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Measure_Spaces)) $(E,\cal{E})$ relative to some non-negative measure $\mu:\mathcal{E}\to[0,+\infty]$, one proves the following theorem.

> **Theorem.** Let $\cal{N}=\cal{N}(\mu)$ be the set of all subsets $N\subset E$ such that there exists $N'\in\cal{E}$ satisfying $N\subset N'$ and  $\mu(N')=0$. Then
>   $$\begin{array}{rcl}
> \sigma(\cal{E}\cup\cal{N})
> &=&
> \lbrace B\subset E\mid\exists~A,C\in\mathcal{E}, A\subset B\subset C~\,\&\,~\mu(C\setminus A)=0\rbrace \\
> &=&
> \lbrace B\subset E\mid\exists~A\in\mathcal{E},\exists~ N\in\mathcal{N}, B=A\cup N\rbrace
> \end{array}$$
>   and there exists a unique measure $\overline{\mu}$ on the $\sigma$-algebra $\overline{\mathcal{E}}=
> \overline{\mathcal{E}}^{\mu}
> =
> \sigma(\cal{E}\cup\cal{N})$
>   extending $\mu$, and $(E,\overline{\mathcal{E}},\overline{\mu})$ is a complete measure space.

In view of this proposition, consider the following definition

> **Definition.** Let $(E,\cal E)$ be a measurable space. An $\cal E$-**null class** is a set $\mathcal{N}\subset\mathcal{P}(E)$ such that
>
> 1. $\emptyset\in\cal N$
> 2. $\forall ~N\in\mathcal{N},\exists N'\in\mathcal{N}, N\cup N'\in\cal E$
> 3. $\forall ~(N_n)_n\in\mathcal{N}^\mathbb{N}$, $\bigcup_n N_n\in\mathcal{N}$
> 4. $\forall ~U\subset N\in\mathcal{N}$, $U\in\mathcal{N}$.
>
> Let us furthermore say that $\cal N$ is **non trivial** if $\lbrace\emptyset\rbrace\neq \mathcal{N}$.

Clearly, if $\mu$ is a non-negative measure on $(E,\mathcal{E})$, then $\mathcal{N}(\mu)$ is an  $\cal E$-null class. One easily extends the first half of the previous theorem to the setting of null classes :

> **Proposition.** Let $(E,\cal E)$ be a measurable space and let $\cal{N}$ be an $\cal E$-null class. Then
>   $$\begin{array}{rcl}
> \sigma(\cal{E}\cup\cal{N})
> &=&
> \lbrace B\subset E\mid\exists~A,C\in\mathcal{E}, A\subset B\subset C~\,\&\,~C\setminus A\in\mathcal{N}\rbrace \\
> &=&
> \lbrace B\subset E\mid\exists~A\in\mathcal{E},\exists~ N\in\mathcal{N}, B=A\cup N\rbrace\,.
> \end{array}$$

Let us call $\sigma(\cal{E}\cup\cal{N})$ the **completion** of $\cal{E}$ with respect to the $\cal{E}$-null class $\cal N$.

---

### Questions :

1. Suppose $\cal{N}$ is an $\cal E$-null class. Does there exist a measure $\mu$ such that $\mathcal{N}=\mathcal{N}(\mu)$ ?
2. Are the completions of $\cal E$ with respect to non trivial $\cal E$-null classes special (say, in the complete lattice of $\sigma$-algebras on $E$) ?
3. If $\mathcal X\subset\mathcal{P}(E)$ is a collection of subsets of $E$ such that 
   $$
   \lbrace A\cup X \mid A\in\mathcal{E},~ X\in\mathcal X\rbrace$$
   is a $\sigma$-algebra (which must equal $\sigma(\cal{E}\cup\mathcal X)$).
   Does there necessarily exist an $\cal E$-null class $\mathcal N_{\mathcal X}$
   such that $\sigma(\cal{E}\cup\mathcal X)$ is the completion of $\cal E$ with respect to the $\cal E$-null class $\mathcal N_{\mathcal X}$ ?

The second question is a little vague. One way to make sense of it is to ask whether one can in some sense recognize those $\sigma$-agebras $(\cal E\subset)~\cal F$ that are the completions of a $\sigma$-algebra $\cal E$ with respect to a non-trivial $\cal E$-null-class $\cal N$ :
$\mathcal{F}
=
\sigma(\cal{E}\cup\cal{N})$

Comment: I don't have time to really consider your question now, but I thought it might be helpful to note that an "$\cal E$-null class" as defined above is nothing more than a (nonempty and nontrivial) [$\sigma$-ideal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-ideal) of subsets of $E.$ Also, possibly the mathoverflow question [Which Sigma-Ideals in a Sigma-Algebra are Ideals of Null Sets?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153939/which-sigma-ideals-in-a-sigma-algebra-are-ideals-of-null-sets) could be of use.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thank you for the links. The notion of $\sigma$-ideal is different. But the two notions may be related by some "completing under subsets" procedure. Also, condition 2 does not appear in the definition of $\sigma$-ideals.

Comment: Ooops, you're correct. I didn't look close enough before I googling some links and jotting down my comment.

Comment: The answer to the third question ought to be **No!**

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You were right, $\mathcal{N}$ is a sigma-ideal of $\mathcal{P}(E)$ !